# Минимущества или Минимущество в именительном падеже?

Tags: выбор-слов

Минимущества или Минимущество в именительном падеже? Если расшифровывать, то «министерство имуществА».

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас в документах и в оф. пабликах в ВК фиксируется "Минимущество".
Стоит заметить, что года до 2012 использовалось примерно в равных пропорциях "Минимущества" (и. п.) и "Минимущество":

> Уже известно, что Минимущества по новому закону собирается
> приватизировать через ADR более 4% акций НК «ЛУКОЙЛ», находящихся в
> госсобственности (2002);

> Основные акционеры: Минимущества РФ ― 51%, группа «Промышленное развитие» ― 31, 3% (2012);
>
> Акционеры банка полгода игнорировали постановление правительства о
> передаче банковских долей ГУПов в Минимущество, однако после
> очередного скандала 5 февраля акции были переданы (2003).

Как я понимаю, сокращения, подобные этому, со временем перестают восприниматься как сокращения и обретают черты обычных слов. Поэтому, к примеру, есть Минцифры (средний род), а есть Минфин (который в статьях и заметах фигурирует в мужском роде).

Comment: Я тут нашла... Грамота пишет с А

Comment: Да, в орфографическом словаре так зафиксировано. Тем не менее устойчивая тенденция имеется к окончанию среднего рода в и. п. Викисловарь уже фиксирует только так: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: ну если я напишу О, а Грамота пишет А...то как бы ошибка выходит...

Comment: Возможно, в следующем издании словаря уже будет средний род. Пока что можете писать так, как вам хочется, потому что Грамота говорит одно, а документы говорят другое. Глянем, например, Распоряжение Минимущества РФ от 17.10.2000 N 771-р: "...представить акт приема-передачи в Минимущество России..."

Comment: Правильно: Минимущество. А откуда там А в И.п.? Современное полное название: Министерство имущественных отношений Российской Федерации (Московской области и т.д.). Слово склоняется. Вопрос № 251601  Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Это слово нужно склонять. https://sklonili.ru/минимущество. Это раньше было Министерство имущества (Минимущества), оно не склонялось.